# Whle converting dict to serializer, serializer.is_valid always False in Django

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, active-model-serializers

My cmd:

```
python manage.py shell
from user.models import UserInfo
from user.serializers import UserInfoSerializer
import io
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
u=UserInfo.objects.all()[0]
s=UserInfoSerializer(u)
j=JSONRenderer().render(s.data)
o=io.BytesIO(j)
d=JSONParser().parse(o)
s1=UserInfoSerializer(data=d)
s1.is_valid()
```

But the issue here is that s1.is_valid() always comes out to be False and I can't save s1 as a serializer.
I'm getting this error:

```
>>> d
{'username': 'user001', 'password': 'pass001', 'email': 'user001@example.com', 'contact': 9876543210}
>>> s001=UserInfoSerializer(data=d)
>>> s001.is_valid()
False
>>> s001.validated_data()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
>>> s001.validated_data
{}
>>> s001.data
{'username': 'user001', 'password': 'pass001', 'email': 'user001@example.com', 'contact': 9876543210}
>>> s001.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/imharjyotbagga/PycharmProjects/DRF/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 182, in save
    'You cannot call `.save()` on a serializer with invalid data.'
AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` on a serializer with invalid data.
>>>
```

So how can I go about this!?

Comment: You can use `s001.errors` to let the serializer show what the problem is.

Comment: could you paste your serializer class?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to show `.errors` attribute to even try to diagnose the problem. My blind guess would be you messed up your password field. But you won't get any definitive answer unless you produce the code of your serializer, model, and the `.errors` of your serializer would also be really helpful.